# Android set layout to take the rest of height

Tags: android, layout, screen

How to set the height of one layout to take the entire height left?

The First Layout take 150 height and Second Layout take 50 height, i want the the Third one take the rest of height, I may be need to get the screen size of device, then set the parameter of Layout, how to do these?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150.0dip">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_imagegallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="144.0dip"
                android:layout_height="144.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:tag="sticky"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_textview_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_imageview"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_textview_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_imageview"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_imageview"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RadioGroup
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40.0dip">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_radio_1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/offer_button_caption"
                    android:layout_weight="5.0"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_radio_2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/description_button_caption"
                    android:layout_weight="5.0"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.itprovent.fotokodroid.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: i am not getting the Question Please Elaborate.

Comment: Can you improve your question? Can you put an image so we know, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question, i also attach an image

Answer (score 0):

If all three layouts at the same level then you can do following.

Update:
    HorizontalScrollView = > set height 150dp
    RelativeLayout => set height 50 dp

```
<com.itprovent.fotokodroid.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/composite_complex_and_sticky_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
```

Comment: Thank you, but the outer layout, must ScrollView

Comment: Set your parent LinearLayout height to fill_parent. In your code it's wrap_content.

Comment: But the androidstudio will show warn and say that the height must be wrapcontent, is it okay to ignore this? and actualy that also didn't  help

Comment: Yes. You have to try and see yourself.

Comment: i compile your and bellow answer suggestion (fill parent for linear layout, weight 1 0dp for CustomViewPager), and edited my question code, but it still didnt work

Comment: Looking back to your problem. You said "set layout to take rest of height." It is bit misleading. It is used when you want to show something on screen without scrollview. If you just have three views in scrollview and none of them have layout_height=match_parent or fill_parent. Then it should just work.

Comment: I updated my answer. If first two views have defined height then last one should just be wrap_content. Which means take as much height as the content. When you have ScrollView then total height equal to the height to content, it's not device height.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, ill try that, but if still fail, ill try another way

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this structure...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dip" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the outer layout, must ScrollView

Comment: Thank you, i try your updated answer, but android studio still show third linear layout with 0px height,

Comment: Yuou are setting `10` in `android:layout_weight=""` for the last view which will be `1`.

Comment: try using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `fill_parent` for `ScrollView`.